# Android: CheckBox only selected when I click on grid?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I'm using some checkboxes that are inside a cardView which is either inside a scrollView. Since checkBoxes contain a considerable text size option, my application is not very smooth because it is not able to scroll when I click in pieces of display that contain text from checkbox. Is there any option that allow to a checkBox only to be selected if I click on grid of checkBox and not in the text? I didn't find anything...

Thank you